# How does putting the variable for empty list alter this python code?

Tags: python, recursion, flatten

I am trying to write a code to flatten any nested list using recursion. This was the first code I wrote:

```
def flatten(NL):
    a = []
    for i in NL:
        if type(i) == int:
            a.append(i)
        elif type(i) == list:
            flatten(i)
    return a
```

However, it kept returning an empty list until I changed the code and put the variable "a" outside the function:

```
a = []
def flatten(NL):
    for i in NL:
        if type(i) == int:
            a.append(i)
        elif type(i) == list:
            flatten(i)
    return a
```

I have tried to wrap my mind around it to no avail. How has putting the empty list outside the function affected it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put `a` outside of the function, you are always modifying the same `a`, but when you put it inside, you are redefining `a` each time.  Since you just say `flatten(i)`, and you don't actually do anything with the flattened version, `a` is not affected by the flattening.  You need to add the flattened version to `a`:

```
def flatten(NL):
    a = []
    for i in NL:
        if type(i) == int:
            a.append(i)
        elif type(i) == list:
            a += flatten(i) # Here we add the flattened version to a instead of just creating it.
    return a
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After I read your answer, I did some reading and saw I could have just extended a with each recursive call.

`
flatten(NL):
    a = []
    for i in NL:
        if type(i) == int:
            a.append(i)
        elif type(i) == list:
            a.extend (flatten(i)) # Here we add the flattened version to a instead of just creating it.
    return a
`

Comment: Yes.  That definitely seems to be a better solution.  One thing to note, though: you should use `if isinstance(i, list):` instead of `if type(i) == list:` (same thing with `int`) so that instances of subclasses of `list` will still fall under that category.  If you found my answer useful, please consider marking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use recursion, you are somewhat "double dipping" by also having a for loop.

For recursion through a list operate on the head and recurse on the tail.  There is no need to declare your own list at all, that just makes it more difficult.

```
def flatten(NL):
    if type(NL) == list:
        if not NL:
            return NL    #empty list terminate recursion
        return flatten(NL[0]) + flatten(NL[1:])
    return [NL]     #'scalar' value terminate recursion
```

Here is an example

```
>>> flatten([[1,2],[3,[4,5]],[6,7]])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```